# Vue template compile error, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c')"

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-nova, vue-loader

I'm working on adding a custom tool to an existing Laravel application using Laravel Nova for the admin panel. The auto generated tool that is created with "php artisan nova:tool vendor/name" doesn't seem to work out of the box. It shows in the Nova menu (added it to the NovaServiceProvider.php) but when I open it nothing renders and the browser console returns this error.

The exact stack trace and error I get is:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:226 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c')
at Proxy.render (admin-agenda:142:22)
at Wn (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:816:16)
at Ee.fn (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5701:46)
at Ee.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
at R.e.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:51)
at R (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822:5)
at D (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612:5)
at B (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565:9)
at y (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040:11)
at Ee.fn (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708:11)
```

This seems to a very generic error usually related to vue, vue-loader and vue-template-compiler version mismatches. I've minimalized the Tool.vue componenent to the bare minimum for testing purposes.

Current Tool.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello, world!'
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is the package.json from the Tool:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
```

VS the package.json from the parent project:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
        "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.4.4",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
        "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^1.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.8",
        "cropperjs": "^1.5.11",
        "json-logic-js": "^2.0.0",
        "mix": "^0.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "smoothscroll": "^0.4.0",
        "tinymce": "^5.7.0",
        "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-meeting-selector": "^1.1.3",
        "vue-select": "^3.16.0",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^3.9.0",
        "webpack": "^5.77.0"
    }
```

### Things I've tried

- update everything to the latest version, broke the project for the most part and seems like more work than working out this error.
- put every matching dependancy at the same version, doesn't seem to change much.
- delete node_modules and npm install anew
- delete vendor and composer install anew
- added VueLoaderPlugin to webpack.mix.js

I've tried more things but these were the most obvious things IMO.

#### Thanks in advance!

Comment: nova 4 is using vue 3, Try to check `vendor/laravel/nova/package.json`. If it's the issue, you will have to upgrade to vue3, or downgrade nova to version 3, which supports vue 2

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP?

Comment: Currently upgrading to vue3, will report results. Thanks for the suggestion @Lk77

Comment: @Lk77 upgrading vue to the supported version fixed my issue, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestion from @Lk77 I upgraded to vue 3 because the project used Nova 4, this resolved the current error!